# For a sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n+1}-a_n|$ converges implies $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I know that when the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n+1}-a_n|$ converges, then we have $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\rightarrow 0$
So by using this I was going to prove that the sequence $a_n$ is Cauchy. But couldn't come up with a correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: For every $n \geq 0$, $p \geq 0$, $$|a_{n+p}-a_n| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}{|a_{k+1}-a_k|}.$$

Comment: Can you please explain more.

Comment: Triangle inequality.

Comment: Yes. But how does this leads to the convergence of the sequence?

Comment: This proves $(a_n)$ to be Cauchy.

Comment: Seems like I'm missing a theory? I'm sorry but still don't get it.. Why does the above inequality says that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $p>0$ and $n>N$, $|a_{n+p}-a_n|<\epsilon$ ?

Comment: The fact that the series converges proves that the right hand side in my inequality goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Ah I se. Thank you. You are referring to this.. isn't it? 

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tail_of_Convergent_Series_tends_to_Zero

Answer (score 0):

$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k+1}-a_{k}|.$

Since $S_n$ converges , $S_n$ is Cauchy.

$\epsilon >0$ given, there exists a $n_0$ s.t. for $m \ge n \ge n_0$

$|S_m-S_n| =|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}|a_{k+1}-a_{k}||$

$=\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}|a_{k+1}-a_k| < \epsilon.$

Show that $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy.

For $m \ge  n \ge (n_0 +1)$ we have:

$|a_m-a_n| \le |a_m-a_{m-1}|  +..$

$|a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}|+.......|a_{n+1}-a_n| $

$=S_{m-1}-S_{n-1} \lt \epsilon.$

Hence Cauchy, hence convergent.